# What software companies offer Linux based laptops?

Tags: technology

I've been using a Linux laptop for years now, mostly when working at startups (as a developer) and also for home usage.

Recently, I've moved to a medium sized (~1000 employees) company, where we have an IT department. All employees are obligated to use Macs. I talked to the IT and they cannot offer any other solution except Macs and Windows (legacy).

Linux (Ubuntu + UI customizations) is a personal preference. Makes me much more productive. Not starting a war. Everyone entitled for an opinion.

It would really be nice to know if there are software engineering work places that support Linux work laptops.

* Not talking about Linux on a VM. Talking about the full experience.

Comment: Better posted on a computing Stack.

Comment: I worked in companies in the past that only allowed Windows, or only Macs, or even only Linux. Sometimes there were combinations possible like you had the choice between Mac or Linux, but Windows was a no-go. There are good reasons for an IT department to keep the list of operating systems small in the company or to change policy over time. If you only want to work with a specific OS then you should ask about that as soon as possible in the interview process. The only company I know that did provide Macs or Windows and forced all employees to use Linux was SUSE (a Linux company)...

Comment: If this matters to you, ask in the interview.

Comment: What is your actual question? You know that "there are software engineering work places that support Linux work laptops" because you say you've worked at some.

Comment: Companies usually force Macs (sometimes Windows) if they have poor and lazy IT support which could not bother with supporting various OS in local LAN etc.. Therefore they stick with one hardware and software supplier, receive kickbacks and nobody rocks the boat until some smart ass developer comes along :)

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question directly: Thousands of them.

To answer the question why they are enforcing mac is very simple. We allow choice of system in my company, we have people using Macs, Linux, and recently Windows ... Every week there's "hey there's a bug here", few people waste few hours debugging only to find there's indeed a problem in a library, but not exactly bug, because library is only designed to be used on Linux Servers.

This is something many companies do not want to deal with, so they mandate same OS as they us in production, or one that is already in majority in organization - so there's no compatibility issues.